# Unexpected validation behavior in Angular using ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation

I'm experiencing some weird validation behavior using Angular's built-in form validator. On my username `<input>` field, I have a ng-pattern that allows only letters or numbers (`ng-pattern="/[A-Z0-9]/i"`).

But the validation doesn't work the way I expect it to. For example, it recognizes the username input is invalid when I type in a bunch of symbols e.g. `!@#$`. But if I start off with a few letters and then type in a bunch of symbols, such as `SomeUser!@#$`, it will throw a validation error on the first symbol, `!`, but when I type in the second symbol `@`, it turns the error back off. Every 3rd or 4th symbol I type in it will toggle on/off the error again.

I've tried looking at the Angular docs but I don't see anything that indicates I'm implementing `ng-pattern` incorrectly.

Here is the code:

```
<form name="signupForm" ng-submit='signup()'>
    <input name="nameInput" type='text' ng-model='user.username' ng-pattern = "/[A-Z0-9]/i">
    <input name="passwordInput" type="password" ng-model='user.password' ng-pattern = "/[A-Z0-9]/i">
    <button>signup</button>
</form>
<span class = 'error' ng-show="signupForm.nameInput.$invalid && signupForm.nameInput.$dirty">Invalid username</span>
```

Comment: _"I have a ng-pattern that allows only letters or numbers"_ - No. You have a pattern that allows **anything** as long as there is one letter or number in it. You only get an error message once in a while because the \g flag lets the next check start at the last match instead of the beginning of the string.

Comment: Yup, my regexp was incorrect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
<input name="nameInput" type='text' ng-model='user.username' ng-pattern="/^[A-Z0-9]*$/i">
```

The [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) explicitly states that you should not use the g flag.

The asterisk in the regexp means 'zero or more', so the empty string will be regarded as valid. You could use '+' instead ('one or more'), but this implies that the error message will appear right away, when the user hasn't typed anything in the input field yet. You could use ng-required instead.

Comment: I guess `/i` modifier is allowed.

Comment: Yes, sure, I have added the /i to my answer. Thanks!